# Use linq to find items that appear in two lists

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm trying to find items that appear in 2 lists. I have found existing examples using simple lists but they do not appear to be what I need.

Here's a paired down example:

```
List<SiloNode> NodeList = new List<SiloNode>();

public class SiloNode
{
    public List<string> Groups;
}
```

**NodeList** is a list of **SiloNode** and each item contains a list of **strings** in **Groups**.

Firstly, I extract a single node from **NodeList** which represents the current page, so I have this:

```
SiloNode currentNode = // code to get this node
```

So, now having the current node, I want to find all other nodes in **NodesList** that contain any of the group items in **currentNode.Groups**.

I've looked at examples using .Contains and .Any but these only demonstrate comparing simple properties such as string or int, and so far I can't come up with the correct syntax.

For example, the code below only lets me compare against a single string:

```
public static IEnumerable<SiloNode> GroupMembers(this SiloNode currentNode)
{
    return NodeList.Where(x => currentNode.Groups.Contains(x.Key));
}
```

Can anyone help me get to where I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect) extension method

```
return NodeList.Where(x =>  x.Groups.intersect(current.Groups).Any());
```